# Integrate WPF and Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am learning WPF and was wondering if there is a way to show a WPF Window from an existing C# WinForm without 'hosting' WinForm in WPF? 
I tried using  myWPFWindow.show() on button click event for displaying the Window. The window is getting displayed  but the textboxes displayed in the window are preventing me from typing. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a strange problem I also ran into one year ago. I don't exactly remember the solution, but [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/442782b1-00a1-4e2e-9cc6-ae99b6699126/) should point you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The suggested forum was very helpful. It works now.